# How do I add playlist index to an already downloaded youtube playlist done without the indexes originally?

Tags: scripts, downloads, youtube, youtube-dl

I used to download youtube playlists using `youtube-dl` with the command

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo[height<=?720]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/bestvideo[height<=?720]+bestaudio/best[height<=?720] -o '%(playlist_title)s/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s'
```

although I have rectified it by switching to `%(playlist_index)02d-%(title)s` so that I get the index numbers from now on, but is there a method by which I can add index numbers to already downloaded playlists which were downloaded using my earlier command syntax.

So If I have a folder with downloaded videos from a particular playlist, how do I add indexes to the filenames with `youtube-dl` if I know the playlist url.

Comment: Please provide feedback for this.

Comment: @taurus05 I just added the playlist indexes manually, can't seem to find a solution yet ..